# Edit source directly on Ubuntu VM from Windows host

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I'm playing around with Django on a guest Ubuntu minimalist VM (no window manager).  What's the best workflow for this?  I think it would be best to be able to edit my files directly in my Windows IDE without having to SFTP or git between editing OS and server.

Is it even possible to map my home directory in the Ubuntu VM to a windows share?

edit: VMWare Player (the free version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your VM. I know VirtualBox allows you to define "Shared Folders" which are directories on your host that are exposed to the guest. For example, I share my "F:\myproject" directory to my Ubuntu guest, where it is mounted just like any other file system (`mount -t vboxsf [share-name] [directory]`).

Answering your actual question though: If you want to map your actual home directory to a windows share, I suggest you look at [Samba](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba). That'll let you expose your home directory to your network, with password protection (ie, your Ubuntu credentials).

Comment: VMWare has a similar feature to VBox's shared folders: http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html. Once you have the shared folder setup you can view it by following the instructions here: http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_sharedfolder_viewing.html.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one obvious thing would be to setup a Samba share on Ubuntu and then you can treat the files in your UbuntuVM like it was on a Windows share.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but it looks like a major configuration PITA, I'm hopinh VMWare provides an easier way.

Comment: It's not all that hard. The NAT subsystem of the virtual machine software might give you some trouble -- you might have an easier time getting *out* from the VM rather than *in* from the host -- in that case, you could just keep the code directory on the host, and automatically mount it from the guest.